# What's the FDA recommended sous vide temperature for in-shell egg pasteurization?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, sous-vide, pasteurization

## My problem

I am trying to figure out the official FDA guideline for time and temperature of in-shell egg pasteurization process in heated water (sous vide).

## What have I tried

- Googled this site, including [How to pasteurize eggs in a sous vide machine (in the shell)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/how-to-pasteurize-eggs-in-a-sous-vide-machine-in-the-shell)
- Googled the [FDA site for egg safety](https://www.fda.gov/food/guidanceregulation/guidancedocumentsregulatoryinformation/eggs/ucm170615.htm), but did not find a concrete answer.

## My Question

**What are official FDA guidelines for temperatures and times for home egg pasteurization in sous vide?**

Comment: Why do you think that there are such guidelines? Even assumed that they want to, the technique is relatively new, and it takes time to do the necessary research and agree on guidelines. Also, there is little reason for them to do so. They rarely create guidelines by technique, the topic is already covered by existing technique agnostic guidelines, there is not much political or social interest in creating them, there have been budget cuts and movements towards them creating less regulation... all in all, I find it unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer from the [FDA website](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/ORAU/Pasteurization/PAS_05_summary.htm) for pasteurizing whole eggs:

> Egg pasteurization uses a water bath and motion to ensure that whole eggs are pasteurized without cooking the eggs.
>
> Egg whites coagulate at 140 °F. Therefore, heating an egg above 140 °F would cook the egg, so processors pasteurize the egg in the shell at 130 °F for 45 minutes.