# Accidentally refrigerated Mayonnaise

Tags: storage, mayonnaise

I did this at where I work.  I stock incoming orders for a restaurant and I was putting un-opened jars of mayonnaise in the refrigerator.  The chef did not see them in the dry food section and kept ordering more.  So we ended up with surplus of mayonnaise before the chef caught me in wrong-doing.

Was the mayonnaise ruined?  Is it O.K to just put it back in the dry food section?

Comment: The mayonnaise was not ruined, but you will have to find a way to use it up before the expiration date, so you may still end up throwing out lots of mayonnaise if your surplus is too large.

Comment: how long does mayonnaise last?

Comment: There is no way to tell you a number in days, as it depends on the process, contents, packaging, date of production, etc. There should be an expiry date printed on the container; if not, call the manufacturer or supplier and ask them.

Comment: If the mayonnaise was never opened while it was refrigerated, you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason that they should be harmed in any way by their sojourn under refrigeration.  In fact, since the rate of chemical reactions is directly related to temperature, their shelf life may have been slightly extended.

You can move it to dry stores.

While [there are some circumstances](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33212/room-temperature-rest-for-fresh-mayo) where very fresh mayonnaise should be kept at room temperature, that does not apply to the commercial product.