# Pasteurized eggs in homemade mayo?

Tags: eggs

If you are using pasteurized eggs or pasteurized egg yolks when making mayonnaise is it still necessary to leave the mayo out at room temperature for the recommended 24, or more, hours?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please add a reference: Who says mayo should be left at room temperature for 24h? And why?

Comment: @Stephie - the question is likely referring to [this process](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/33212/15018), which is used to make homemade mayo safe, even in the case of contaminated eggs.

Answer (score 3):

The main rationale for the "[room temperature rest](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33212/room-temperature-rest-for-fresh-mayo)" for homemade mayo is to kill off potential *Salmonella* in eggs.  Most other ingredients in mayo recipes should not be contaminated with bacteria, so I can't imagine any benefit from the room temperature rest when using pasteurized eggs.

In fact, given that mayo will degrade faster at room temperature (in terms of flavor and quality), it would keep the mayo fresher for longer if you refrigerate immediately.