# What is the shelf life of my home made coleslaw dressing?

Tags: salad, salad-dressing, storage-lifetime

I made about a gallon of dressing today from Kraft mayo, apple cider vinegar, and sugar.  What is the shelf life of this?

Also, what is the shelf life of balsamic vinegar, salad oil, garlic, honey, salt and pepper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: I don't see the generic article as a duplicate when it doesn't cover the particular case.

Comment: Seems like those are two entirely different topics

Answer (score 1):

Your coleslaw dressing is almost certain to be sufficiently acidic as to have an essentially unlimited (call it at least a month or two) in the refrigerator.   Commercial mayonnaise is acidic enough off the shelf to discourage bacterial growth pretty well, and you have enhanced its acidity with the cider vinegar.

The balsamic dressing--it is difficult to say.  It depends on how acidic it is, and that depends critically on the recipe.

See also:

- [Room temperature "rest" for fresh mayo?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33212/room-temperature-rest-for-fresh-mayo)
- [Making "long(er)-life" homemade mayonnaise](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/making-longer-life-homemade-mayonnaise/23371#23371)

Comment: ok .. Just wondering, so ur pretty certain on that i felt it would be the other way around.. been cooking professionally for like 10 years.. ok the balsamic had in it. 1/2 gallon balsamic vinegar/ 1 gallon salad oil. . quart of honey tsp dry mustard, salt and pepper and 8 cloves garlic minced... fully blended with immersion blender..

Comment: The issue is that balsamic vinegar ranges from sugar syrup to moderately acidic, and there is no standardization, so I cannot give you any particular advise.  Assuming it is sufficiently acidic, it will also last a long time, but that depends on the nature of the specific vinegar you used.  I am guessing it is not the traditional product in that kind of quantity.

Comment: well its a modena brand that comes in 2 gallons at a time, anyway the issue i would be concerned with is the garlic, however i think the vinegar will take care of that.  im also wondering if there are preservatives that can be used.

Comment: I found out the balsamic vinegar I was using is 6% acidity