# shelf life question regarding mayonnaise based sauce

Tags: mayonnaise

I make this mayonnaise based sauce that my friends all rave over and I wanted to make a large batch, can it (which I've never done before) and give it out as a gift. I'm nervous about giving away something without understanding how long it can be preserved in the refrigerator.

The sauce has 1 part white wine vinegar, 1 part water and 6 parts mayonnaise, in addition to minced garlic and other spices. Any ideas on how long this might last, or where I can find better literature about preserving in general?

Comment: http://nchfp.uga.edu/

Comment: As you can see from the linked question, the shelf life is up to 5 days (refrigerated), maybe less. There are no home preservation methods which will let you keep the taste. Also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/making-longer-life-homemade-mayonnaise